# How can I generate a preview of an HTML page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-3.5

Are there any ASP.NET APIs for generating a GIF/JPG/PNG preview of an HTML page?

Comment: You want to generate thumbnails of webpages... server side?  That's a very expensive task.  Just ask SearchMe: http://www.techcrunch.com/2009/07/24/searchme-may-go-offline-tomorrow/

Comment: http://fastflip.googlelabs.com/ figured it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser:

```
public void CaptureWebBitmap()
{
    WebBrowser browser = new WebBrowser();
    browser.Size = new Size(200, 150);
    browser.ScrollBarsEnabled = false;

    browser.Navigate("http://www.stackoverflow.com");

    while (browser.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
    {
       // release temporary e.g. some threading resources ...
    }

    Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(200, 150);
    browser.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, new Rectangle(browser.Location.X, browser.Location.Y, browser.Width, browser.Height));
}
```

but you must run this function in new STA thread

```
Thread threas = new Thread(new ThreadStart(CaptureWebBitmap));
threas.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
threas.Start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a .NET library, but its not free.

[Websites Screenshot](http://www.websitesscreenshot.com/)